# Linefeed when using copy for text files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file `a.txt`

```
hello
there
```

and a text file `b.txt`

```
how
are
you?
```

By using `copy a.txt+b.txt c.txt` I get a `c.txt`

```
hello
therehow
are
you?
```

How do I need to change the command to get a new line/linefeed between `there` and `how`?

Comment: Nothing you can do with the `COPY` command.  You need to get a CRLF at the end of A.txt. `echo. >>a.txt &copy a.txt /A + b.txt /A c.txt`

Comment: @Squashman You probably meant "Nothing you cannot do"

Comment: No.  That would be a double negative.  Let me rephrase that.  There is nothing you can change with the COPY command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant, but it works:

```
for %%a in (a.txt,b.txt) do type %%a >>c.txt && echo. >>c.txt
```

There will be a blank line at the end of the last file in the list though.

If you want to use wildcards:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do type "%%a" >>c.txt && echo. >>c.txt
```

Comment: How would you use it with `copy *.txt c.txt`?

Comment: @P.Dee, using wildcards like `copy *.txt c.txt` is not a good idea, since `*.txt` also matches the target `c.txt`, which may lead to unexpected results...